# Implementing large linear regression models using CUDA

Tags: cuda, linear-regression, matrix-factorization

For analysis of 10^6 genetic factors and their GeneXGene interactions (~5x10^11), I have numerous and independent linear regression problems which are probably suitable for analysis on GPUs.

The objective is to exhaustively search for GeneXGene interaction effects in modulating an outcome variable (a brain phenotype) using linear regression with the interaction term included.

As far as I know, the Householder QR factorization could be the solution for fitting regression models, however, given that each regression matrix in this particular work could easily approach the size of ~ 10'000x10, even each single regression matrix does not seem to fit in GPU on-chip memory (shared, registers etc.).

Should I accept this as a problem which is inherently bandwidth-limited and keep the matrices in GPU global memory during regression analysis, or are other strategies possible?

**EDIT**
Here are more details about the problem:

There will be approximately 10'000 subjects, each with ~1M genetic parameters (genetic matrix:10'000x10^6). The algorithm in each iteration should select two columns of this genetic matrix (10'000x2) and also around 6 other variables unrelated to genetic data (age, gender etc) so the final regression model will be dealing with a matrix like the size of 10'000x[2(genetic factors)+6(covariates)+2(intercept&interaction term)] and an outcome variable vector (10'000x1). This same process will be repeated ~5e11 times each time with a given pair of genetic factors. Those models passing a predefined statistical threshold should be saved as output.

The specific problem is that although there are ~5e11 separate regression models, even a single one does not seem to fit in on-chip memory.

I also guess that sticking with CUDA libraries may not be the solution here as this mandates most of the data manipulation to take place on the CPU side and only sending each QR decomposition to GPU?

Comment: Go high-level first. Try to reduce your problem to common linear algebra routines and use [CUDA libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries) (there are tons of them: e.g. cuBLAS and cuSolver might already have what you need). Defer inventing your own stuff and worrying about bandwidth until you really need this.

Comment: Why your problem size suddenly changed from 10^12 to 10000*10?

Comment: @Drop Thank you. But considering that there will be 10^12 separate regression models, will this be efficient?

Comment: size of "an outcome variable vector" ? you mean solving `A(10000x10) X(10x1) = B(10000x1)` ?

Comment: @kangshiyin you are correct. Ouctcome variable will be equal to number of subjects (a brain measure):10'000x1.

Comment: why do you want to fit a single A to register/shared mem? cuSolver expect an A stored on global mem.

Comment: This is a least squares problem X(10'000x10)xBeta(10x1)=outcome(10'000x1) and is a good candidate for Householder QR factorization

Comment: it is what cuSolver will do, isn't it? and 10000x10 sounds like a (almost) large enough size to fully utilize the GPU. so I don't get why you think it is too large..

Comment: @kangshiyin so you suggest building all possible iterations of A by CPU and transfering them to GPU Global memory, then calculating with cuSolver? Won't this make PCI transfer a bottleneck as moving chunks of the original genetic matrix to GPU and building A there will be traveling of less enormous data?

Comment: you could build an A by GPU, which means you can store the data (1e4 x 1e6) in global mem first. If the data is too large, you have to use PCIe, but there's way to make it much faster than your proposal

Comment: @kangshiyin thank you. Will have a look at cuSolver. Is this also the way to go if the matrix is a bit smaller like 1000x10 instead?

Comment: i think it may be too small. you have to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You whole data matrix (1e4 x 1e6) may be too large to fit in the global memory, while each of your least squares solving (1e4 x 10) may be too small to fully utilize the GPU.

---

For each least squares problem, you could use cuSolver for QR factorization and triangular solving.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-lt-t-gt-geqrf

If the problem size is too small to fully utilize the GPU, you could use concurrent kernel execution to solve multiple equations at the same time.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/

---

For the whole data matrix, if it can not fit into the global memory, you could work on only part of it at a time. For example you could divide the matrix into ten (1e4 x 1e5) blocks, each time you load two of the blocks through PCIe, select all possible two-column combinations from the two blocks respectively, solve the equation and then load another two blocks. Maximize the block size will help you minimize the PCIe data transfer. With proper design, I'm sure the time for PCIe data transfer will be much smaller than solving 1e12 equations. Furthermore you could overlap the data transfer with solver kernel executions.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds trivial, but from what I understand, this means that I should transfer two chunks of the large genetic matrix to GPU, then enumerate blockXblock interactions using a loop from the host side, and in each loop iteration send "device pointer offsets" for the two columns selected from the input matrix to cuSolver, each time using a new stream created by cudaStreamCreate()? Could you give me a hint how best this offsetting could be carried out in a loop in host code?

Comment: @sourena your words about stream is correct. You need to copy two columns from the blocks to build the matrix A, not just two pointers. You could forget about the stream and overlapped data transfer first.

Comment: I just don't get this sentence in your answer "each time you load two of the blocks through PCIe" : OK now I suppose two fragments of the big matrix are in GPU global mem. Then you have commented "You need to copy two columns from the blocks to build the matrix A". Either I should build the ten columns of A in host side and then transfer this to GPU for analysis by cuSolver, or I would rather transfer chunks of the main large matrix to GPU, and then build the ten column A in device side before proceeding to cuSolver?

Comment: transfer chunks of the main large matrix to GPU, and then build the ten column A in device side before proceeding to cuSolver -- this minimize the PCIe data transfer.